# Java arraylist add data an transform to .txt

Tags: java, object, for-loop, arraylist

This is my code in which I try to write data(Ime-name, Pasma-breed, Starost-age, Teza-weight) in to arraylist an then from array list to .txt file. It has to be done for 5 Dogs(Pes) so I have used for i was hoping if someone could check it and give me a feedback to this. I have got problems with writing to array list and then to .txt file.

Thanks :)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Pes {
    private String Ime;
    private String Pasma;
    private int Starost;
    private double Teza;

    public void setIme(String Ime) {
        this.Ime = Ime;
    }

    public String getIme() {
        return Ime;
    }

    public void setPasma(String Pasma) {
        this.Pasma = Pasma;
    }

    public String getPasma() {
        return Pasma;
    }

    public void setStarost(int Starost) {
        this.Starost = Starost;
    }

    public int getStarost() {
        return Starost;
    }

    public void setTeza(double Teza) {
        this.Teza = Teza;
    }

    public double getTeza() {
        return Teza;
    }

    Pes() {
        Ime = "";
        Pasma = "";
        Starost = 0;
        Teza = 0;
    }

}

public class Aplikacija {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new File("Psi.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Vpišite ime!");
            String Ime = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Vpišite pasmo!");
            String Pasma = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Izberite starost!");
            int Starost = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Izberite tezo!");
            double Teza = input.nextDouble();

            Pes Pes1 = new Pes();
            Pes1.setIme(Ime);
            Pes1.setPasma(Pasma);
            Pes1.setStarost(Starost);
            Pes1.setTeza(Teza);
            new ArrayList<Pes>();
            Pes1.add(new Pes(Ime, Pasma, Starost, Teza));
            input.close();
        }

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Psi.txt");
        for (String str : arr) {
            writer.write(str);
        }
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: *I have got problems with writing to array list and then to .txt file.* Can you describe these problems? Do you get some errors/exceptions? If so could you spot informations from them?

Comment: Your `Pes` class doesn't have `Pes(String Ime, String Pasma, int Starost, double Teza)` constructor so you can't use `new Pes(Ime, Pasma, Starost, Teza)`. Anyway why would you want to do it? You already have `Pes1` instance with this informations from user. Also DON'T CLOSE `Scanner` reading from `System.in` because it will also close `System.in` and you will not be able to write anything.

Comment: `Pes1.add(new Pes` What is this suppose to do? Why you are creating `new ArrayList<Pes>();` in each loop iteration? What is `arr`?

Comment: I am a bit of a new to java. Pes1.add(new Pes this should add Pes1 to array list

Comment: my whole code is kinda wrong lol :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `BufferedWriter`

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Psi.txt");
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
for (String str : arr) {
    bw.write(str);
}
writer.close(); // or use try-with-resources if you use Java SE 7
bw.close();
```

See [How to write in file](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/) tutorial for instance.

Or you could use `PrintWriter` which is simpler in your case.

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("psi.txt", "UTF-8");
for (String str : arr) {
    writer.println(str);
}
writer.close();
```

Comment: You are giving solution but not explaining the problem. Could you add more info about which part of writing to file in OP code was wrong?

Comment: I am asking because this part in PO code looks OK, as opposed to MANY things before that part: lack of `toString` in `Pes`, adding `Pes` to `Pes`, closing `System.in` in loop, creating and not using ArrayList, wrong constructors of `Pes`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
      import java.io.*;

      class class_Name
   {
     //your code 

       try
     {
       File file = new File("../filename.txt");
       FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
       BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);
         for (String str : arr) 
          {
           writer.write(str);
           }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
       e.printstackTrace();
     }

   }// end of Class
```